# How do I build a dynamic array and loop through it in AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I was reading the official [AutoIt Array Parameters](http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Arrays), and from what I can tell you have to tell AutoIt how many elements your array has before you can even create it. Since my array will be dynamic according to what the user selects in my interface then I am in need of something like this.

From their page:

But say you don't know the size of the array upfront, because it may come in a variable size when created dynamically.

```
Local $iMax

Local $data="Element 1|Element 2|Element 3"

; The string in data will be split into an array everywhere | is encountered
Local $arr = StringSplit($data, "|")

If IsArray($arr) Then
     $iMax = UBound($arr); get array size

     ConsoleWrite("Items in the array: " & $iMax & @LF)

     For $i = 0 to $iMax - 1; subtract 1 from size to prevent an out of bounds error
     ConsoleWrite($arr[$i] & @LF)
     Next
EndIf
```

I have set up an `if` statement to go through the users selections and build the array first:

```
If GUICtrlRead($Box1) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
   $data = "one|two|three"
EndIf
If GUICtrlRead($Box2) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
   $data = "four|five|six"
EndIf
If GUICtrlRead($Box3) = $GUI_CHECKED Then
   $data = "seven|eight|nine"
EndIf
```

If the user selected all three boxes I would need something like:

```
$data = one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine
```

Then at this point I can pass these elements into the example above to loop through all my elements.

How can I build the array through multiple `if` statements and come out with one large array?

Comment: I figured it out by using `$data &= "one|two|three"` will Concatenation assignment and add them together. https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm. Then I just ran a regular `For $i = 0 to $iMax - 1` loop to get the results I needed.

Comment: You could also create an array with lets say 10000 entries and then Redim the size to what you need.

Comment: Use Array.au3 UDF
eg. _ArrayAdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UDF function _[*ArrayAdd*](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayAdd.htm) for this purpose. For example,

```
#include <Array.au3>
Local $arr = []      ; NOTE this creates an array of size 1 with an empty string
_ArrayAdd($arr, 'lorem')
_ArrayAdd($arr, 'ipsum')

For $i = 1 To UBound($arr) - 1
    ConsoleWrite('arr[' & $i & '] == ' & $arr[$i] & @CRLF)
Next
```

---

OR you can use .NET class *[ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)*. That is more flexible:

```
Local $arr = ObjCreate('System.Collections.ArrayList')
$arr.Add('lorem')
$arr.Add('ipsum')
$arr.Add('dolor')

ConsoleWrite("Contains 'dolor'? " & $arr.Contains('dolor') & @CRLF)

$arr.Sort()
For $i = 0 To $arr.Count - 1
    ConsoleWrite('arr[' & $i & '] == ' & $arr.Item($i) & @CRLF)
Next
```